# Setting keyboard shortcut

Tags: 14.04, live-cd

I have a following file to set the keyboard shortcuts for the Input method. It is working correctly as expected.

> /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/keyboard.gschema.override

```
[org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings]
switch-input-source=['<Primary><Shift>m']
switch-input-source-backward=['<Primary><Shift>e']
```

Is it possible to have 2 keys for "switch-input-source" parameter? I will like to add F9 key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter more keyboard combinations, separating the quoted string representing your key presses by a comma, e.g. as in

```
switch-input-source=['<Primary><Shift>m','F9']
```